# How to set filter to All in a filter's condition formula in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I am currently writing a formula in a filter *MyFilter*'s condition (shown below).  I am trying to make it so that it will use the *MyParameter*'s value as a filter if *MyParameter*'s value is not *All*.  In the case that it is *All*, then I would like it to not filter anything.  I.e., Display all values.  Here is what I have so far, which is incorrect.  How might I be able to achieve the desired outcome?  Thank you in advance for any help that you may offer.

```
IIF([MyParameter] != "All", // TEST CONDITION
[MyFilter] = [MyParameter], // THEN BLOCK
[MyFilter] = "ALL") // ELSE BLOCK
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you essentially don't want the filter to *filter* anything in the case where your parameter is set to 'All'.

There are 3 pieces to this:

1. [MyParameter]- Your parameter that includes values and 'All'
2. [FilterField] - The field you want to use to filter against the parameter value
3. [FilterCalc] - A calculated field to use in the filter card

The [FilterCalc] would have this logic:

`[MyParameter] = 'All' OR [MyParameter] = [FilterField]`

And just make sure you set [FilterCalc] 'True' once in the filter card.

> Note that this is almost no different than putting the [FilterField] directly in the filter card. The only difference is that you explicitly restrict the values in your parameter ([MyParameter]).